# How to produce a *bidirectional* infinite sequence?

Tags: sequence

Infinite sequences with a specific starting point are well-understood by now. For example, the Fibonacci numbers can be programmed like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954407/96588):

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

It's used by either taking a specific number of items from the resulting generator or taking items as long as a condition like `a < 30` holds.

**Is there a standard approach for doing this with sequences which are infinite in *both* directions,** such as [the bidirectional Fibonacci numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghxQA3vvhsk)? That one is fairly simple, since the Fibonacci numbers before zero (1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8, etc.) are easily derived from the positive ones, but consider one where no such symmetry exists. Is a generator even appropriate for such a sequence? Can you yield values as they are produced (1, -1, 2, down to the minimum and *then* 0, 1, 1, 2, etc.) but have the consumer get them in the right sequence (…, 2, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, …)?

(The mathematical nature of this is incidental; it could just as easily apply to sequences of strings or images.)

Comment: I don't see any difficulty. I suppose the difficulty you see is purely due to the limitation of generator. It is true that a generator can only be used to generate a sequence in one direction. For both directions, you will need to use one generator for each direction. Meanwhile, if you re-think the whole problem in terms of dynamic program from first principles, i.e. "to compute the next result(s) by reusing previously computed results in new calculations, there is nothing that stops one from computing bidirectional infinite sequences.

Comment: This feels more like mathematics problem than programming problem.

Comment: @Euphoric As mentioned it could just as easily apply to a sequence of any type of object. The question is how to sensibly create code around such a problem, even given a fairly trivial sequence.

Comment: I myself stumbled upon that video yesterday :) In the context of programming, the way to look at this is to ask what is the interface going to be (in the sense of how client code is going to use it). The generator/iterator approach is organized around an interface that lets you obtain the *next* element in some sequence, so it's inherently unidirectional in nature. Now, you can do something like return pairs of elements expanding in both directions, or come up with an ordering scheme (e.g, indices 0, 1, -1, 2, -2...), but these are probably not that useful, except in specific situations. 1/2

Comment: If you have a formula though, then you can, in principle, produce any element given an index - just allow negative indices. So for that sort of use case an ordinary function should be fine, and it seems like that approach is more generally useful. Sometimes you may want a range of elements between two indices, and generators & iterators can be used for that. Or you can parameterize the direction - again, it all depends on how other code is going to use it. 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović That sounds like I suspected, that there's no established universal pattern for doing this. Not sure why it's being downvoted though, do people not like questions that can't be answered easily?

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes, it would be helpful if they left comments. But my guess is that it's in part because some people perceive it to be more of a math question, rather than a question about software engineering.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with a sequence that is infinite in both directions? Is it a sequence where, given a starting point you can infinitely request both the next and the previous element in the sequence? Or is a sequence where the starting point is at (negative) infinity?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau The former, as in the given example of the bidirectional Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I knew I should've invented some string-based or other sequence as well. To me this clearly has nothing to do with maths, and everything to do with how to structure code to produce results from a sequence which is infinite in both directions.

Comment: You would need to roll your own, bidirectional generator/iterator. most programming languages only have standard support for unidirectional generators/iterators. I'm not familiar with python, but it looks to be that way in python, too.

Comment: Yes, of course, but not with a generator.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a standard approach for doing this with sequences which are infinite in both directions

There probably isn't, because such sequences are quite rare in practice.

Even for a finite-length bidirectional sequence (a sequence where you can step back, but not necessarily beyond the starting point) is a generator not the best solution. A generator is really good at producing a sequence in one direction, but to step back through that sequence you need to store it in a container of some kind.

If you would ask me to write something that can produce or iterate over a bidirectional infinite sequence, I would write a bidirectional [iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) for it.